# setup.py -- configuration for private / commercial projects

Tags: python, python-packaging

What can I put on our `setup.py` project configuration file to tell the developers that the project is a private/commercial application/library.

Currently I set:

```
setup(
    name='MyProject',
    version='0.1.0',
    license='(c) My Company',
    ...
)
```

Any best practice?

**Note:**

Nowadays, most of the projects are open source, and adhere to the licences model. However, when you work on the industry, software are private. My company works with off-shore companies which may not be aware of the fact that a software can be private. So, I want to bring this fact to their attention by specifying this in the `setup.py` file. This is why I'm looking for best practices about that.

**Conclusion/Solution**

For private/proprietary applications, I will follow [rth's recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44098491/1513933):

- set the license attribute to “Proprietary”,
- add the classifier “License :: Other/Proprietary License”,
- and maybe add a `LICENSE` file.

The template will be something like that:

```
setup(
    name='MyProject',
    version='0.1.0',
    license="Proprietary",
    classifiers=[
        'License :: Other/Proprietary License',
        ...
    ],
    ...
)
```

An alternative could be to set “Not open source”, like defined in the [cookiecutter-pypackage](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter-pypackage/blob/master/cookiecutter.json) template.

Comment: What is the purpose of your desired configuration setting? What do you mean by "tell developers that the project is a private/commercial application/library"? What do you hope to achieve by doing this?

Comment: @polo: I have edited my question to explain that in a note.

Comment: can you explain how do you hope your developers will  "interact" with this config? Will they be actively looking for it (and if so when and how)? Is this config setting something you wish to use in some automated process (if so what automated process and how would this be used)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Technically, there is no fundamental difference between licensing open-source and proprietary software.

In both cases you should include a `LICENSE` file specifying what can and cannot be done with your software (see [this related SO question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/101944/are-there-pre-made-commercial-software-licenses-to-choose-from)). It is also advised to add a short copyright / license header to every code file in your project (in case they get copied outside of the original package folder).

It is possible to mention the license type in `setup.py`, however that field is mainly used to display the license for Python packages uploaded to [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org). Since your code is not open-source (and won't be uploaded to PyPi), this is not very relevant in your case.

Comment: Agree. Our libraries are not uploaded to PyPi. Nevertheless, they are uploaded to a private DevPi server which is also a proxy to the official PyPi. So, we can found Open Source projects in DevPi.  Our (small) community of users must see the license terms in DevPi.

Comment: Just put `licence="proprietary"` or `"proprietary and confidential"` in `setup.py` then describe the details in `LICENCE` file and file headers and it should be fine (see e.g. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/68134/best-existing-license-for-closed-source-code )

Answer (score 1):

if you fear people will upload your package by mistake to pypi, maybe some of those tricks would help [How to disable uploading a package to PyPi unless --public is passed to the upload command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39520987/how-to-disable-uploading-a-package-to-pypi-unless-public-is-passed-to-the-uplo)

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not interested in this feature.